# Executar Redux Saga ao iniciar o app

Tags: react, react-native, redux

Criei um app offline first para executar ações offline e enviar quando estiver online, e funciona bem, mas quando o app é fechado e inicializado novamente a fila de ações não executa pois quem faz a verificação de conexão e dispara a fila de ações é um saga-middleware, e eu preciso que esse saga seja executado quando o app for iniciado.

aquivo `offlineSaga`:

```js
import { put, take } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { eventChannel } from 'redux-saga';
import { NetInfo } from 'react-native';
import { OFFLINE, ONLINE } from 'redux-offline-queue';


export function* startWatchingNetworkConnectivity(){

    const channel = eventChannel(emitter => {
        NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener("connectionChange", emitter);

        return () => NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener("connectionChange", emitter);
    });

    try{

        while(true){

            const isConnected = yield take(channel);

            if(isConnected)
                yield put({ type: ONLINE });
            else
                yield put({ type: OFFLINE });
        }

    } finally {

        channel.close();

    }

}
```

arquivo `saga`:

```js
import { takeEvery, put, call, all, spawn } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import api from './services/api';
// import errorMessage from './errorMessage';
import { startWatchingNetworkConnectivity } from './offlineSaga';


function* asyncEndScheduling(action){

    try{

        const url = `api/auth/driver/updateScheduling/${action.idScheduling}/key/0bff134c-0227-4d31-9c3b-d922f75f3d98`;

        const response = yield call(api.post, url);

        const { schedulings } = response.data.agendamentos;

        yield put({
            type: 'SUCCESS_END_SCHEDULING',
            newSchedulings: schedulings,
        });

    } catch(err){

        yield put({
            type: 'ERROR_END_SCHEDULING',
            error: 'Erro',
        });

    }

}

export default function* root(){

    yield all([

        spawn(startWatchingNetworkConnectivity),

        takeEvery('REQUEST_END_SCHEDULING', asyncEndScheduling),
    ]);

}
```

Preciso executar o `offlineSaga` quando o app for inicado, como posso fazer isso?